# Create Excel Data Table in ClosedXML C# from existing Data

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, closedxml

I am trying to convert the data I already have in a Worksheet in to a DataTable using ClosedXML but I cannot find an overload method for what I need.

This is the code that I am trying:

```
NewWorksheet.Cell(1, 1).InsertTable();
```

The closest overload method is the single with an IEnumerable or DataTable but what would I put in there? There is no overload method that takes a range.

[Here](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Inserting-Tables) is the documentation page but nothing meets my need.

Answer (score 0):

`InsertTable` inserts an existing `DataTable` into the spreadsheet. You want to do the reverse. That's not possible in `ClosedXML`.

Comment: So I cannot convert a range in to a Data Table? That is sad :(

Comment: It's possible, but you will have to write your own code.